# How to override template files in parent theme?

Tags: theme-development, css, child-theme

My parent theme has most of it's codes are divided into pieces and in different folders with different files.

for example, menu's are in one file, search is in another file, etc. and all these files are stored in a folder.

As a newbie to wordpress development, this is confusing me a lot. I'm trying to build a child theme where I need to override all these element's styles and change their locations.

Should I just create a replica of folders and files in my child theme to override them or, just files are good?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, as described in the [documentation](https://codex.wordpress.org/Child_Themes#Template_Files), just make a file or copy from your parent theme to your child theme, that the file will be the equivalent of the parent and will override him. I suggest you to take a time and read the docs.